# C++ Rotate 3x3 grid made of 9 character char array?

Tags: c++

I have a grid that looks like this

```
X . .
. . .
. . .
```

made from a char array, How would I go about rotating it 90 degrees left or right?
would look like

```
. . X
. . .
. . .
```

after 90 degree right rotation

Comment: Observe the transformation of every index and you are good to go

Comment: Can you show the program you've already written, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. We don't write entire programs for other people, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**to rotate the matrix left or in anti-clockwise direction:-**

1. Find transpose of the matrix.
2. Reverse columns of the transpose.

Let the given matrix be

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

First we find transpose.

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

Then we reverse elements of every column.

```
c f i
b e h
a d g
```

**to rotate the matrix right or in a clockwise direction:-**

1. Find transpose of matrix.
2. Reverse rows of the transpose.

Let the given matrix be

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

First we find transpose.

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

Then we reverse elements of every row.

```
g d a
h e b
c f i
```

Code to this Problem

```
void rotate90Clockwise(char a[N][N]) 
{ 

    // Traverse each cycle 
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) { 
        for (int j = i; j < N - i - 1; j++) { 

            // Swap elements of each cycle 
            // in clockwise direction 
            char temp = a[i][j]; 
            a[i][j] = a[N - 1 - j][i]; 
            a[N - 1 - j][i] = a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j]; 
            a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = a[j][N - 1 - i]; 
            a[j][N - 1 - i] = temp; 
        } 
    } 
}
```